# Router.navigation is not working inside the promise

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-router

I tired to navigate from login page to dashboard after google signin is done. The navigate inside the promise after storing the token in localStorage is not working.

From LoginService a googlelogin() return promise after verification and storing. But in LoginComponent which receives returned promise the router.navigation is not working.

## LoginComponent

```
loginwithgoogle(){
    this.loginservice.googlelogin().then(()=>{
      console.log("login");
      this.route.navigate(["../Home"],{relativeTo:this.activatedroute});
    });
  }
```

## LoginService

```
googlelogin(){
    return new Promise(()=>{
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var idToken = result.credential.idToken;
        localStorage.setItem('token',idToken);
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Shouldnt you call accept() function somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "success" callback call from your promise

```
return new Promise((successCallback)=>{
    .....yourcode
    successCallback(someReturnValuePassedToThenCallback);
}
```

Thats why I like observables more.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the Promise constructor. Just pass the promise returned by firebase:

```
googlelogin() {
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(/* process response */);
}
```