# router navigate is not executed

Tags: angular, angularjs, routes

I'm coding in Angular.

This is a basic component for login

After complete the form and click on login button this function is triggered

```
  loginFn() {
    this.authService.loginFn(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
    })
  }
```

But the route never changes, so I have to do this "trick" to work

```
  setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']), 10);
```

I don't like to use it in that way, I feel I'm missing something

Anybody knows what is wrong?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263062/router-navigation-is-not-working-inside-the-promise) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing related to the change detection cycle in Angular. When you call this.authService.loginFn(email, password) within the loginFn function, it might trigger a change detection cycle that prevents the route change from occurring immediately. This is why the setTimeout workaround seems to work.
You can use also ChangeDetectorRef to manually trigger a change detection cycle rather than using setTimeout.

```
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  loginFn() {
    this.authService.loginFn(email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried with this code but still doesn't work

Comment: I've solved it using a subscription of authstate Subject at constructor level, so the router navigates when authstate changes to a valid user

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mustahid, and you can use Observable mechanism like using RxJS library which allows you to trigger router immediately, also makes you achieve event-based programming conveniently.

```js
  loginFn() {
    this.authService.loginFn(email, password)
     .subscribe((userCredential) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
    });
  }
  
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
  
  constructor(public http: Httpclient){}
  loginFn(email: string, password: string){
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('email',email);
  formdata.append('password',password);
  return this.http.post<any>('/login',formdata);


}
```